# Jenkins hack to use svn export instead of svn checkout?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Has anyone hacked, er, improved Jenkins to allow use of `svn export` instead of `svn checkout`?  The time savings is substantial (1 minute versus 12 minutes) on my repo.

There's an issue in the Jenkins queue to provide this feature, but it has been languishing there since 2008.  https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-1304

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can open an **Execute Shell** or **Execute Windows Batch Command** build steps, and just type `svn co` as you please

Comment: Yes, which is roughly what I'm doing now, but that seems to cause SVN polling to not function.

Comment: You can specify an SVN root-level module, and set **Repository Depth** as empty. Call the folder something like `poll-check`. This will provide the polling, post-commit-hooks, and even then `SVN_REVISION` variables, but won't do the checkout (besides creating an empty folder). You could probably even reuse the module folder name for your manual export